# How to cross-stitch finely on a T-shirt

Tags: embroidery, cross-stitch

I would like to cross stitch a 100x50 point design onto a T-shirt, but I'd like it to be small (4x2 inches approximately). This leaves me with a 25 count per inch design.
Ideally, I'd like to use waste fabric and pull it out after I'm done stitching. Is that feasible, or would I be better off stitching onto even weave and leaving it in?

I'm looking for anyone with experience in high inch-count cross stitching.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  I know nothing about cross stitching, but let me point out a couple of confusing points in the question you might want to check or clarify  just in case they're confusing to others, also.  1. A 100x450 point design in 4x2 inches: the aspect ratios aren't the same, so the pattern would be distorted unless the stitches are different sizes in the two directions.  Also, 25 count/inch doesn't seem right or consistent.  2. How would you remove fabric after you've sewn through it?  This could all make perfect sense to cross stitchers, though.  Good luck with this.

Comment: @fixer1234 good catch- I meant 100x50. The fabric removing thing makes sense for cross stitching- it’s common to add fabric on top the fabric you’re cross stitching to give yourself a sturdier canvas and a nice grid to stitch through

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by the 25 count per inch, I assume your stitches will be about 1 mm each, which is extremely tiny for any kind of cross stitch embroidery.  I doubt you can get a fabric which is fine enough to meet that thread count and still be loose enough to embroider over and take out the threads afterwards.

I would go instead to stabilizing the fabric itself on its back, with interfacing fabric or 'non-woven material' which you can leave on after embroidering.

Select a quality shirt which has the grain of the fabric straight and wash it so you are sure that it will stay that way before you spend the effort of working on it.  Make sure you have the fabric completely flat and straight, and iron it on with the advised heat, so it sticks the best it can.

Work you embroidery with the material in a ring (or other frame) so it can not stretch at all while working. Stretching it will release the fabric attached to the back.  Use the knit of the fabric as your counting guide.

After you have finished the embroidery you can take away all the interfacing that is not actually in the embroidered area, but be careful not to damage anything in the process.

I would advise to go for a different process myself. I would embroider on a suitable fabric and applique that onto the shirt. This way you can save the work once the shirt is worn out and transfer it to a different garment.